# using class property in other classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have defined this class

```
const ERR_MSG = 'Error1';


@Service()
export class MutationValidator {
..
}
```

that I use in another class

```
import { MutationValidator }     from './mutation.validator';

const mutationValidator = new MutationValidator();

mutationValidator.ERR_MSG
```

but I have this error when compiling

```
Property 'ERR_MSG' does not exist on type 'MutationValidator'.
```

Comment: ERR_MSG is not a member of class MutationValidator. it is declared at module level of "mutation.validator".

Comment: ERR_MSG should be inside the class, otherwise it’s just a loose variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to export `const ERR_MSG = 'Error1';` Similarly how you have exported your Service class `MutationValidator`.

More over as it is defined outside the scope of `MutationValidator` you cannot call it from `MutationValidator`.

There are two possible solutions

First export the const and then use it:

```
export const ERR_MSG = 'Error1';

@Service()
export class MutationValidator {
..
}
```

and then use it in the another class as

```
import { MutationValidator, ERR_MSG }     from './mutation.validator';

const mutationValidator = new MutationValidator();

console.log(ERR_MSG);
```

or else you can also define the value of `ERR_MSG` inside the `MutationValidator` class as a public variable and use it like below

```
@Service()
export class MutationValidator {
  ERR_MSG = 'Error1';
  ..
}
```

and in another class you use it like

```
import { MutationValidator }     from './mutation.validator';

const mutationValidator = new MutationValidator();

console.log(mutationValidator.ERR_MSG);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Service()
export class MutationValidator {
  ERR_MSG = 'Error1';
}
```

it should work now